# Self-contained awk script: Saving to file, calling file

Tags: bash, input, awk, io, output

For a lab, I wrote a shell script that used awk to do some stuff. Rereading the lab's directions, it seems that I was supposed to write a self-contained awk script. I'm working on translating my bash script into awk, and I'm having a problem right now:

I want to save the output of an awk command to a new file, and then I want to use that output as input for another awk command.

In my bash script, I have this:

```
awk '/Blocked SPAM/' maillog > spamlog
cat spamlog | awk '{print $0}' RS=' '
```

It takes all the lines from maillog that contain the string "Blocked SPAM" and saves this to a new file titled spamlog. Then it opens spamlog and replaces every space character ' ' with a new line.

For my awk script, maillog is the file that is passed to the script from shell. My attempt at writing analogous code:

```
/Blocked SPAM/ > spamlog`
-f spamlog {print $0} RS=' '
```

I don't really know what I'm doing with my awk script since I'm having trouble finding useful resources for self-contained awk scripts.

Comment: Consider editing your question above to include 1. sample input (simplified to cover the basic requirement), 2. required output based on that input, 3. your current output. Then most/all of the ambiguity of what you are trying to achieve will be eliminated. Good luck.

Comment: awk isn't really geared to self-driving like that. I think you might have an XY problem here. I think you probably need to rethink your methodology to get yourself a single awk flow that can do what you want (remember you can give the same file to awk more than once and use a `NR==FNR` match to operate on the first (but not second) pass through it).

Comment: The usual awk idiom for `{print $0}` is `1`.  That is, your second command would normally be written `awk 1 RS=' ' spamlog`, although most people would probably write `awk '1' RS=' ' spamlog`

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/Blocked SPAM/{ print > "spamlog"; gsub( " ","\n"); print }' maillog
```

Personally, I prefer to invoke that directly from a shell script, but you can easily make it an awk script by writing:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/Blocked SPAM/{ print > "spamlog"; gsub( " ","\n"); print }
```

Invoke that script with 'maillog' as an argument.

Comment: Thanks William. I have instructions to write the code in only one script. How would I call spamlog in the awk script that has already invoked maillog as the argument?

Comment: What do you mean?  `spamlog` is a data file, why do you want to 'call' it?  The answer I gave generates `spamlog` and also produces the result of processing it.

Comment: I want to use awk's search function on spamlog, in the same script that created it. When I was using bash, I would just replace maillog with spamlog in my awk search, but I don't know how to do the same here. Your code seems to save the output to the file spamlog, and then prints it out as well.

Comment: You can either write data to spamlog and then read spam log to process it, or be more efficient and write data to spamlog and then immediately process it (which is what this solution does).  Why do you want to read the file instead of just processing the data?  As far as I can tell, this solution does exactly what you want.

Comment: Sorry William, when I try your solution, it just saves and prints out spamlog. I don't know how to use your solution to search through spamlog after creating and printing it. Maybe I am supposed to replace the last `print` you have, with whatever command I want to execute on spamlog?